# How to Multiple take picture using crossmedia

Tags: xamarin.forms, xamarin.android, xamarin.ios

How to Multiple take picture using Crossmedia, I use this it works perfectly  but it will navigate again and again but i don't want this

```
bool isCamera = true;
while (isCamera)
{
file = await MediaPicker.TakePhotoAsync(new StoreCameraMediaOptions { SaveToAlbum = true, Name = "", Directory = "" });
if (file != null)
{
//save code}
else{
isCamera=false;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The plugin doesn't support multiple select . So we need to  use dependency service for each platform to implement it.

To pick media from gallery yourself. Check this [Tutorial](https://medium.com/swlh/select-multiple-images-from-the-gallery-in-xamarin-forms-df2e037be572).

For Android

```
public void OpenGallery()
{
    try
    {
        var imageIntent = new Intent(Intent.ActionPick);
        imageIntent.SetType("image/*");
        imageIntent.PutExtra(Intent.ExtraAllowMultiple, true);
        imageIntent.SetAction(Intent.ActionGetContent);
        ((Activity)Forms.Context).StartActivityForResult(Intent.CreateChooser(imageIntent, "Select photo"), OPENGALLERYCODE);
        Toast.MakeText(Xamarin.Forms.Forms.Context, "Tap and hold to select multiple photos.", ToastLength.Short).Show();
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(ex.ToString());
        Toast.MakeText(Xamarin.Forms.Forms.Context, "Error. Can not continue, try again.", ToastLength.Long).Show();
    }
}
```

For iOS , you could use the plugin https://github.com/roycornelissen/GMImagePicker.Xamarin

Comment: I expected to get help for  they can take(take functionality not pick) multiple images and then click save using xamarin forms. Apart from crossmedia any other to do that so...

Comment: Why don't you implement it by yourself ?